# Access Last Element of Array

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I'm trying to access the last element in an array in C++ (more specifically, I'm trying to convert an integer into a character array and then access the last digit).  Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
int number_to_convert = 1234;
char * num_string;
sprintf(num_string, "%d", number_to_convert);
printf("Number: %d Sizeof num_string: %d Sizeof *num_string: %d Sizeof num_string[0]: %d\n", number_to_convert, sizeof(num_string), sizeof(*num_string), sizeof(num_string[0]));
```

Using this info I tried several different combinations to access the last element:

```
num_string[sizeof(number_to_convert)/sizeof(*number_to_convert)-1];
num_string[sizeof(number_to_convert)-sizeof(char)]
```

Maybe there's a better way to get the last digit, but this is the best way I could find.  I want the last character (not the null character).

Comment: Did you mean **num_string[sizeof(num_string)-sizeof(char)]** instead of **number_to_convert[sizeof(number_to_convert)-sizeof(char)]**

Comment: num_string has not been allocated memory in your example, that's hazardous. You should also keep the return of sprintf as it give you the total number of characters actually written. Also It is prefrred to use snprintf rather than sprintf

Comment: Does that code even compile? You are trying to dereference an int variable (number_to_convert).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the last decimal digit of `n`, try `n % 10`.

To get the textual numeral character for that digit, use `'0' + (n % 10)`.

For any other number base, replace `10` with that base.

---

The "because I can" way:

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << n;
char last_digit = *s.str().rbegin();
```

Or even:

```
const char last_digit = *static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << n).str().rbegin();
```

Comment: This works great thanks, but I'm also curious how to do it the way I showed, even if it is more complicated.  I'm learning about arrays/pointers right now, and converting a number to a c-string and then taking the last element seemed like a good way to do this.

Comment: Nah, that's not very C++. If anything you could use a string stream and formatted output. Note that you used `sprintf` wrong -- it's best not to stay clear of those lethal C functions if you're not well at home with manual memory management.